# Error in sys.path.insert to reference a github module

Tags: python, jupyter, sys.path

I am trying to use a module from github called ffn and have downloaded it to my desktop. I am using Jupyter notebook for Python and was told i need to insert this code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Users\...\Desktop\ffn-master\ffn\_core_.py")
import ffn
```

..in order to use this code.
However when i run the subsequent lines of code that call functions from here I still get the error:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ffn\core.py:2054:
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in minimum
>   negative_returns = np.minimum(returns, 0.)

I restarted the kernel and everything but still get the same error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should try to keep packages you are consuming to the path you are working in.  It allows for not only more modularity, but if something happens and the file is removed later on from the desktop, it wont kill the codebase.

Comment: I was told by the project developers to have it in a different path away from where the regular anaconda is hence I tried the desktop. The desktop module has the fixes that the installed module in the anaconda path does not. As the path is not "taking" it's still looking up the old module which does not have certain fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The desktop module has the fixes that the installed module in the anaconda path does not." - It seems like you still have the original module installed in the anaconda library.

try running

```
conda uninstall ffn
```

and then include the entire library in the path in you notebook with

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\...\Desktop\ffn-master\ffn\")
```